# how to count number of values in mysql table where one field can contains more than 1 values

Tags: php, mysql, count

i have a table name user_feedback where i store userfeedback.

In this table i have one column , name product_id where i store the products id IE-

```
     f_id  f_name      product_id
       1      x          5
       2      y          1,3
       3      z          1,5
       4      A          2,3,4,7
```

And the product table is -

```
 product_id   pname
      1      samsung
      2      apple
      3      micromax
      4      vivo
      5      sony
      6      lenovo
      7      xolo
```

How to know the number of product count of each products

ex-

```
        prdname       count
        samsung       2
        apple         1
        micromax      2
        vivo          1
        sony          2
        lenovo        0
        xolo          1
```

Comment: Have you control over the database structure? This model could be improved quite a lot to make this kind of queries much easier

Comment: @StefanoZanini - sorry i didnt get u ? please can u help me to find out above solution

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over those tables structure, I'd suggest implementing a proper N:N relationship, removing the `product_id` from the `feedback` table and creating a new table `prod_fb_rel` with only `product_id` and `f_id` as columns

In that table you'd have

```
f_id  | product_id
   1  |          5
   2  |          1
   2  |          3
   3  |          1
   3  |          5
   4  |          2
   4  |          3
   4  |          4
   4  |          7
```

And the query you need would be as simple as

```
select  prdname, count(*)
from    product t1
join    prod_fb_rel t2
on      t1.product_id = t2.product_id
group by prdname
```

**Edit**

To populate the new table starting from the data you have now, you probably should define a `split` function (like [this one](http://You%20should%20define%20a%20%60split%60%20function%20[like%20this](https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/)%20and%20write%20a%20procedure%20that%20for%20each%20records%20loops%20on%20the)) and then write a procedure that takes each existing record, loops on the number of IDs in the `product_id` and in each iteration uses the `split` function to extract an id and insert it in the new table.

Comment: Thanx a lot , this is the perfect way to sortout this query, but one major problem is how to make new table with existing 2500 records in user_feedback table

Comment: I edited my answer with a brief explaination on how you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (if you can't change the structure) (but pay attention at performances...):

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (F_ID INT, PRODUCT_LIST VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE T2 (PRODUCT_ID INT, PNAME VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (1, '5');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (2, '1,3');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (3, '1,5');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (4, '2,3,4,7');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (1,'samsung');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (2,'apple');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (3,'micromax');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (4,'vivo');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (5,'sony');
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (6,'lenovo');

SELECT PNAME, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T1 WHERE (CONCAT(',' , T1.PRODUCT_LIST,',' )) LIKE CONCAT('%,', CAST(T2.PRODUCT_ID  as CHAR ) ,',%') ) AS RC
FROM T2;
```

Output:

```
    PNAME   RC
1   samsung 2
2   apple   1
3   micromax    2
4   vivo    1
5   sony    2
6   lenovo  0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  pname, count(*)
from    product t1
join    user_feedback t2 on FIND_IN_SET(t1.product_id,t2.product_id) 
group by pname;
```

Just try above code.Hope this will helps.

Comment: Dude Your Are great , Thanks a lot , both answers solves the query.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you cannot do that directly. From my point of view, you first need to explode all product_id in an array (using PHP explode function), then you can count all products for a given pname. Let me know if you need more info.